# how do I set application path in image background url?

Tags: css

I have this website.

It has images.

This is load the image correectly.

```
<img src="~/images/news2.jpg">
```

It appends the application name in production server.

Now If I have

```
 <div class="bg" style="background: url(~/images/camels1.jpg)"></div>
```

it is not loading image ?

I need append application path in the url

Any reason ?

Comment: I think you're just missing quotes. Can you try 

`style="background: url('~/images/camels1.jpg')"` 

?

Comment: @hungdoansy not working

Comment: Try to check if the image is there, and if your (empty) div has `width` and `height`.

Comment: is there but application path camelrace is not there

Comment: so If i make it camelrace/images/camels1.jpg it works

Comment: So you've answered your question yourself.

Comment: Try adding `width` and `height` to the div as well. If they're missing, the image is not shown.

Comment: lol I can hard code it, I need soultion but not hard coding the path

Comment: Your actual problem is not CSS problem.

Comment: yes my propblem is setting the path in css with application  path

Comment: so you need to look at the thing that serves the image (webserver or whatever) and be more specific on that in your question.

Comment: @kosh so what can I do now

Comment: I'd suggest to edit your question and add more details on what setup/environment/webserver you're using.

Answer (score 0):

i  fixed it by changning html structure.

```
 <div class="col l3 m6 s12">
                    <div class="new-box new-box-text">
                        <div class="empty"></div>
                        <div class="bg">
                            <img src="~/images/news1.jpg">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and img max-width: fit-content !important;